# var_dump returns "tring(34) " - what is that?

Tags: php

## code

```
var_dump($parse);
var_dump($parse['email']);
```

## output

```
array(2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "newsletter"
  ["email"]=>
" string(34) "ksjdlfjslfkjsadflkjasdf@gmail.com
}

"tring(34) "ksjdlfjslfkjsadflkjasdf@gmail.com
```

The output looks odd.. The `type` value with type looks ok, but `email` looks strange.. the quotes is arround the type and not the value

Comment: Are you sure you copy pasted correctly ? 34 is obviously the length of the `string`, but if you're really getting `tring`, well...

Comment: what you want to know?? your `"tring(34) "ksjdlfjslfkjsadflkjasdf@gmail.com` is wrong looks like.

Comment: it seems, The array also not correct

Comment: He asks what it is, i think he copy paste it wrong.
in the array there is String .
I put the string in a character count it matches the string given.

Comment: The first value `type` looks right but look at `email`.. quotes is arround the type and not the value

Comment: And yes.. I copy / pastes the output correctly

Comment: *sigh* Have you checked the html output?

Comment: content-type: text/plain

Answer (score 4):

The email addresses you dump end with the [`CR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) ("Carriage Return") character.

When it is sent to a terminal, the `CR` character tells the terminal to send the cursor to the first column while keeping the row. The next characters sent to the terminal are then printed over the existing characters on the same line, replacing them. Because the `CR` is the last character in the strings you dump, the next printed character is `"` (the string closing marker) and it appears on the first column. On the second invocation of `var_dump()` the first characters on the line are `string` and `"` overwrites the first one of them.

The source of the `CR` character at the end of the email is, most probably, an incorrectly trimmed string, loaded from a file generated on Windows. Windows uses a pair of `CR` and `LF` characters to mark the end of lines on text files. Linux and macOS use only [`LF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_feed) ("Line Feed").

In order to properly cleanup the text read from files you should use the PHP function [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). It strips multiple types of white space characters from the boundaries of the provided string, `CR`, `LF` and `space` being the most common.

Answer (score 0):

its the type of your variable (string) and the charcount! check the function at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

edit: you edited your question. so now it shows your type of variable (array) and all information about items in the array. (type, charcount(length)...)

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type,value and its length.

in your case `34` is the length of `string`.

you can find more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0):

I just had this as well and as a side effect I couldn't call the value by key, it would just be empty so I searched and found this thread.

Example:

$array = array(1) {
      ["user"]=>
    " string(9) "jamestoa
    }

and
`echo $array["user"]` would be empty on the console.

This was caused by a newline character `\n` at the end of the string which somehow caused this behaviour.

You should use `trim()` on that email to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

In your case for some reason its actually not "tring" but "string". For some reason the information dumped didn´t get the first letter.

"tring(34) "ksjdlfjslfkjsadflkjasdf@gmail.com" is your email variable in your array.

I also seem to see a mistake in your code which would be the reason your getting that output.

```
array(2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "newsletter"
  ["email"]=>
" string(34) "ksjdlfjslfkjsadflkjasdf@gmail.com
}

"tring(34) "ksjdlfjslfkjsadflkjasdf@gmail.com
```

Right after **["email"]=>** your closing quote should go behind the email address.

Your Code:

```
 " string(34) "ksjdlfjslfkjsadflkjasdf@gmail.com
```

How it should be:

```
 string(34) "ksjdlfjslfkjsadflkjasdf@gmail.com"
```